# Is it possible to retrieve the train rows id within each leaf in a DecisionTreeRegressor of scikit-learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree

Currently, I can retrieve the ID of each node of my grown on my training sample to which each row of my test sample is most likely to belong to:

`tree.tree_.apply(np.array(X_test).astype(np.float32))` where X_test represents the inputs of the decision tree.

But, for each leaf of my grown tree, I would like to get the IDs of my training sample which are contained in it. So that I would know which training sample are the most similar to one test input.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using the "apply" function to my training sample to get the leaf_id it belongs to.

```
def get_nearest_points(self, tr, input_train):
  inside_leaves = {}
  tmp = tr.tree_.apply(np.array(input_train).astype(np.float32))
  leaves_list = set(tmp)

  for leaf in leaves_list:
    inside_leaves[leaf] = [idx for idx, elt in enumerate(tmp) if elt == leaf]
  return inside_leaves
```

inside_leaves is now a dictionary containing for each leaf_id a list of the row involved in this leaf.